# Is there a property to limit Openlayers extent interaction to designated number of geocells or degrees?

Tags: openlayers

In this instance there really isn't much code to share, but here is the document for Openlayers extent interaction:

[Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Extent-Extent.html)

I'm using the extent interaction to allow users to draw a bounding box and I'd like to limit the size of the extent that can be drawn by specifying a number of geocells or degrees. I'm hoping to be able to set the limits before the users draws the extent, but don't see a straight forward way to accomplish this within the OL documents. As of now, the users can simply create an extent of any size then I craft geojson like so:

```
new GeoJSON().writeFeaturesObject([new Feature(fromExtent(extentCopy))],
                { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection:        map.getView().getProjection()});
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Draw interaction to draw a rect: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html

Then listen to the `drawstart` event of the [Draw interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html) to get the drawn object and attach a listerner on its geometry to get its changes: `event.feature.getGeometry ().on ('change', testgeom)`

You can test the geometry changes in the `testgeom` function to prevent changes.

Comment: You can also test the geometry in the geometryFunction of the Draw interaction as the example does to make a circle: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html